# Some questions on Sri Vishnu ji ..

Tags: vishnu, brahma

1) Who or what created Vishnu ji ?
If brahma has come from a lotus of his navel, then what is the origin of vishnu ?
ofcourse the vaishnavs will say Vishnu is parbrahm , so he is without any origin. 
But speaking from hindu texts, what is the origin of Vishnu ?

And what is that ocean and what is the snake on which he reclines ?

Is it merely metaphor ? or is for real in some dimension ?

The ocean is said to be made of milk , but is it milk in the literal sense ?
Also if brahma created the universe, where is that universe in the context of the world in which there's a sky , ocean of milk and vishnu ?

sorry this is confusing to me.

Comment: the two questions are quite obviously not duplicates.

Comment: yes they aren't

Comment: The question is obviously different, but the answers to the birth of Trimurthi should answer the question about Vishnu.

Comment: the other question was how is the world of ocean where vishnu is reclining related to the present universe we live in ??

Answer (score 0):

In rig veda Soma gave birth to Vishnu (9 96 5)

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv09096.htm

> "5 Father of holy hymns, Soma flows onward the Father of the earth,
>   Father of heaven: Father of Agni, Sūrya's generator, the Father who
>   begat Indra and Viṣṇu."

I think this Vishnu is different from the Puranic Vishnu.

In the Brahma Vaivarta purana

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Vaivarta_Purana

> "The text is notable for identifying Krishna as the supreme Reality
>   and asserting that all gods such as Vishnu, Shiva, Brahma, Ganesha are
>   same, and all are incarnations of Krishna"

Siva purana has Siva creating brahma and vishnu.  Mainstream vaishnavite puranas have narayana-vishnu as the supreme deity and Krishna a part of a part of Vishnu.